# Android GridView dynamic app themes

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

I am working on a setup screen that allows the user to change the color theme of the app. I want to use a GridView of colored square images for the user to choose from. Right now I have a toast message that pops with the position in  the color image array when clicked. The following opens my theme activity from a setup menu:

```
themeButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imBtnAccentColor);
themeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SetupContactActivity.this, ThemeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Here's an image of the GridView that the user will choose a theme color from. 
[gridViewTiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVe1s.png)

Theme Activity:

```
public class ThemeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.themes);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(ThemeActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is an ImageAdapter class that helps build the image view based on the number of images in my array of images:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context mContext;
  public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c;
  }

  public int getCount() {
      return mThumbIds.length;
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
  }

  // Create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)   {
      ImageView imageView;
      if (convertView == null) {
          // If it's not recycled, initialize some attributes.
          imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
          imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(320, 300));
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
          imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
      } else {
          imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
      }
      imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
      return imageView;
  }

  // References to the color images
  private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.orange,
        R.drawable.yellow,
        R.drawable.yellow_orange,
        R.drawable.brown,
        R.drawable.medium_grey,
        R.drawable.dark_grey,
        R.drawable.pink,
        R.drawable.light_blue,
        R.drawable.medium_green,
        R.drawable.purple,
        R.drawable.blue,
        R.drawable.brownish_green,
        R.drawable.dark_purple,
        R.drawable.dark_blue,
        R.drawable.green
  };
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  Please could you clarify what you need help with

Comment: I have a grid view of color squares that I would like the user to be able to click on to change the theme of the app to the corresponding color. I'm having some trouble hooking the gridview up to the themes.